# angularjs $rootScope.watch not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plunker, rootscope

I am new to angularjs. I am trying to learn `$watch` property . Here is my [`plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/bGR05gBxCVNIPaH2Nclg).

`rootScope.$watch` property is executing on page load only and not on text change event.
But it works properly with `$scope.$watch`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It will work if you turn it to `Object` , like:

```
  $rootScope.name = { value:'World'};
```

And bind it like:

```
  <input type="text" ng-model="name.value"></input>
```

Working: http://plnkr.co/edit/n4QnivBiRvFMAM91UmIT?p=preview

Here you have a great explanation: [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs)

Comment: its working. but why it doesn't work with string like "$rootScope.name = 'test' "

Comment: @SanjaySalunkhe Because your `MainCtrl`' scope has inherited the `name` from your `rootScope` , and did it "by value". For more deep understanding i suggest you to read Mark Rajcok' post, it puts everything on its places..